# Append text after du output in csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk, du

This is my code so far:

```
sizeFolder(){
  du -h --max-depth=1 --block-size=1M $TMP_DIR | sort -hr | awk '{print $1,$2}'
}
```

This is my output:

```
 ----------------------------
 Fr 6. Jul 10:37:16 CEST 2018
 ----------------------------
 ;
 PV Size /PV Name
 ;
 3775 /usr add (line 1 from textfile)
 1805 /usr/share add (line 2 from textfile)
 1382 /usr/lib add (line 3 from textfile)
 384 /usr/src
 176 /usr/bin
 17 /usr/sbin
 13 /usr/include
 1 /usr/local
 1 /usr/games
 ;
```

How to append text lines from a simple text file to the path name, as indicated in the output?

Comment: Did you checked the `paste` command?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please confirm if all lines of another file should be aligned with all lines of output?

Comment: Yes the du output will be 100 Lines and the textfile contains also 100 lines

Comment: @Poshi thank you. I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

to:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} {print $1, $2, a[FNR]}' textfile -
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like (using bash):

```
i=1
file="..." # replace the value by your file path
max="$(cat $file|wc -l)"
while read -r; do 
  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[0-9]+ ]]; then 
    [[ $i -le $max ]] && echo "${REPLY} add $(head -n $i $file|tail -n 1)" || echo "${REPLY}"
    (( i++ ))
  else 
    echo "${REPLY}"; 
  fi; 
done < <(sizeFolder)
```

Of course, there's many other solution (using `awk` for example).

Demo:

```
$ cat test.txt 
----------------------------
Fr 6. Jul 10:37:16 CEST 2018
----------------------------
;
PV Size /PV Name
;
3775 /usr
1805 /usr/share
1382 /usr/lib
384 /usr/src
176 /usr/bin
17 /usr/sbin
13 /usr/include
1 /usr/local
1 /usr/games
;
$ cat test2.txt 
line1
line2
line3
$ i=1; while read -r; do if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[0-9]+ ]]; then [[ $i -le $(cat test2.txt|wc -l) ]] && echo "${REPLY} add $(head -n $i test2.txt|tail -n 1)" || echo "${REPLY}"; (( i++ )); else echo "${REPLY}"; fi; done < test.txt 
----------------------------
Fr 6. Jul 10:37:16 CEST 2018
----------------------------
;
PV Size /PV Name
;
3775 /usr add line1
1805 /usr/share add line2
1382 /usr/lib add line3
384 /usr/src
176 /usr/bin
17 /usr/sbin
13 /usr/include
1 /usr/local
1 /usr/games
;
$
```

Answer (score 0):

script.sh

```
sizeFolder(){
  # read simple text (given as argument $1)
  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a simpletext < "$1"
  # read output from du
  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a duoutput < <(du -h --max-depth=1 --block-size=1M /TMP_DIR | sort -hr | awk '{print $1,$2}')
  len=${#simpletext[@]}
  # loop over both variables
  for ((i=0;i<=$len;i++))
  do
    echo "${duoutput[$i]} ${simpletext[$i]}"
  done
}
sizeFolder "$1"
```

Call:

```
script.sh simpletext.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `paste` this can be very simple:

```
paste -d' ' <(sizeFolder) test.txt
```

This doesn't take care of the header in you example output but since your code doesn't produce it, I assume that will be added by something different (a surrounding script, e. g.).  Just make sure this script still does this *after* the `paste` has been done.